# Controlling page count increment of Data Driven Pages using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sql, data-driven-pages

I was wondering if there is a way to add coding to Data Driven Pages with python.

I would like to be able to take the "Data Driven Page with Count" and increment the count by one or in some cases two.

For example, I have 10 data driven pages and need to add two more pages to the series i.e.  making the final count 12 pages.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to add the two extra pages in ArcGIS?

Comment: see dynamic text in arcpy.mapping http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002s000000

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding additional pages outside of ArcGIS and will be packaging your pages together later, one possible and easy solution would be to add 2 to the PageNumber attribute in your table in ArcGIS.

You could easily accomplish this in field calculator with:

```
!YourField! + 2
```

And then you could add dynamic text from the data driven pages toolbar >> Page Text >> Data Driven Page Attribute.  Choose the PageNumber attribute. Double click on the text. And change it to something like this:

```
Page <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="PageNumber" domainlookup="true"/> of 12
```

This will output Page #+2 of 12