# Using Data Driven Pages for Page Number with Count?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

I have a set of 100 data driven pages showing different roads.  I would like to export the map book by road.  E.g. one road will be one pdf, another road will be exported to another pdf.

The issue I have is with the page numbering.  I have set each page to have a dynamic page number with count.  At the moment, when I export *Road A*, the page numbers show 'Page 1 of 100', 'Page 2 of 100' etc.

I want *Road A* to have 'Page 1 of 5', 'Page 2 of 5', etc. then *Road B* will have 'Page 1 of 2', 'Page 2 of 2'.

I can't seem to work out how to do this, I'm sure I have done it before, but my terrible memory has failed me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to an earlier question ([Controlling page count increment of Data Driven Pages using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107394/data-driven-page-with-count/107406#107406)).

There's a way you can work around dynamic page numbers.

First of all, in your page number field make sure all of your pagenumbers are how you want them (ex. Road A only goes up to 5, road B starts at 1)

Add dynamic text from the data driven pages toolbar >> Page Text >> Data Driven Page Attribute. Choose the PageNumber attribute. Double click on the text. And change it to something like this:

```
Page <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="PageNumber" domainlookup="true"/> of 5
```

This will output Page # of 5 or whatever number you specify at the end.
For Road B do the same but change the 5 to a 2

Also some additional reading on [dynamic text](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000)